# Backtrace points to fopen crash

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Following is the backtrace I got from a recent crash. 
It points to the fopen call. Not sure whats going on here. 
There is enough space on the device. & Even if the file is not their , it should return NULL.

Crashing does not make sense. 
here is the bt

```
(gdb) bt 
#0  0xb788f50e in __open_nocancel () from /tmp/user_20130523143934/x86/lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0xb78453e7 in *__GI__IO_file_open (fp=0x814b0e4, filename=0xb78fc1f5 "/init_log.cfg", posix_mode=-2, prot=438, read_write=8, is32not64=0) at fileops.c:233
#2  0xb784555c in _IO_new_file_fopen (fp=0x814b0e4, filename=0xb78fc1f5 "/init_log.cfg", mode=0x1b6 <Address 0x1b6 out of bounds>, is32not64=1) at fileops.c:332
#3  0xb783d519 in __fopen_internal (filename=0xb78fc1f5 "/init_log.cfg", mode=0xb78fc1f3 "r", is32=1) at iofopen.c:93
#4  0xb783d55f in _IO_new_fopen (filename=0xb78fc1f5 "/init_log.cfg", mode=0xb78fc1f3 "r") at iofopen.c:107
#5  0xb78fbe00 in init_setup (app_uuid=1009, mod_uuid=0, hdl=0xfffffffe) at ../init_setup_api.c:1013
#6  0x0805f431 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffa64) at .. vpg_agent.c:307


(gdb) frame 5
#5  0xb78fbe00 in init_setup (app_uuid=1009, mod_uuid=0, hdl=0xfffffffe) at ../init_setup_api.c:1013
1013        if ((fp = fopen(MY_FILE, "r")) == NULL) {
(gdb) l
```

Appreciate your help.

PS: One more thing, its a remotely mapped filesystem. Just got to know about it. 
That might be contributing.

Comment: Most probable a memory corruption (maybe just before the `fopen` or even simultaneously if it's multi-threaded application). Or maybe your program is out of virtual memory.

Comment: another process crashed at the same time, that also pointed to fopen

Comment: its a static macro , points to a file location.
Thet shouldnt be problem rt, if its not thr it should return NULL, not crash

Comment: `gdb` tells that you are using `libc` that is not in system's usual path (/tmp/user_20130523...). Maybe the problem is there, you're using non-standard libc (maybe it's tracking files or something like this) and it crashes?

Comment: yes this is non-standard libc, but this has been inplace for years. We just have wrappers around actual function calls. 
these wrappers are not crashing

Comment: This "*... mode=0x1b6 <Address 0x1b6 out of bounds> ....*" smells like a general memory corruption.

Answer (score 4):

The `__open_nocancel` is usually a tiny wrapper around the system call.

Here is what it looks like on my system:

```
(gdb) disas __open_nocancel
Dump of assembler code for function __open_nocancel:
   0x000ddf5a <+0>:     push   %ebx
   0x000ddf5b <+1>:     mov    0x10(%esp),%edx
   0x000ddf5f <+5>:     mov    0xc(%esp),%ecx
   0x000ddf63 <+9>:     mov    0x8(%esp),%ebx
   0x000ddf67 <+13>:    mov    $0x5,%eax
   0x000ddf6c <+18>:    call   *%gs:0x10
   0x000ddf73 <+25>:    pop    %ebx
   0x000ddf74 <+26>:    cmp    $0xfffff001,%eax
   0x000ddf79 <+31>:    jae    0xddfad <open+93>
   0x000ddf7b <+33>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

It is very likely that your PC `0xb788f50e` corresponds to my instruction at `0x000ddf73`, i.e. instruction immediately following the system call itself.

If that's the case, there are several likely explanations:

1. You are looking at the wrong thread, not the one that actually crashed.
   What does `(gdb) info thread` show?
2. Your kernel is unhappy with something happening on the system, and is terminating processes left and right. Check  `/var/log/messages` for clues.

On the other hand, if your instruction at `0xb788f50e` corresponds to my instruction at `0x000ddf6c` (i.e. the `call` itself), then perhaps you've set your `ulimit -s` too low?

Finally, if you have SELinux enabled, it may be terminating you because you are violating its policies. Check appopriate selinux.log.